# Is it better to compile from source or to install from a .deb package?

Tags: compilation, deb

Sometimes, when downloading software from the Internet, I find that there is a .deb package ready for either my Debian/Ubuntu and also a tarball to be compiled. In the beginning I would simply use the package for its ease of installation, and wouldn't even dare attempting to compile. Even the sound of it scared me a bit. Nowadays, however, when I have the option I sometimes find myself in a dilemma: is there an unpopular advantage to compiling from source compared with the .deb package? I hope to find out here, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'd recommend the `deb`, the tarball is for people who are on RPM or otherwise unable to use the deb (Windows, OS/400, and/or special needs which require recompilation with different build options and/or patched source).

Comment: Thanks tripleee for clarifying this issue...